# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time - having issue only in aws server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access a url that ends with .json file from a different server. I have used the below code which is working fine in my development env but when I hosted the in aws server I am getting error.
Sample URL :  https://sample.com/sampledata.json

```
    public dynamic GetHttpData(string urlString)
    {
        string jsonResponse = null;

        try
        {
            Uri getUri = new Uri(urlString);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(getUri);
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, null);
            request.Accept = "*/*";                

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    jsonResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
        }
       
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

The above code works fine in dev but getting the below error in server.

```
An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
System.Net.WebExceptionSystem.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillBufferAsync>g__InternalFillBufferAsync|215_0[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 min, Int32 initial)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithNtAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean isProxyAuth, HttpConnection connection, HttpConnectionPool connectionPool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() System.Net.Requests
```

Comment: Does the AWS machine configured to allow outbound network traffic?

Comment: its an internal secure url that is used to access data from a different system inside our client network.

Comment: So AWS can't access it? Because it is outside your network?

Comment: If it is secure URL then that won't be available over the internet. AWS server tries to connect to that URL via internet.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya its default - All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: that means that AWS machine can connect to internet. but since the URL is not accessible outside client network, AWS machine can not access it. AWS machine is trying to reach the URL over internet.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  I tried to create a sample application replicate the same code with url that is available over internet, I can see the json in the browser but while accessing it via code I am getting this error

Comment: @mjwills I tried with url which is available in internet  its working fine in my local but in server.

Comment: Please share that [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to add time out parameter like this :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(getUri);

// Set the  'Timeout' property of the HttpWebRequest to 600000 milliseconds.
request.Timeout=600000; //10 Minutes
```